# Can I call constructor within an arithmetic expression?

Tags: c++

I am implementing a Matrix class and I overloaded the `*` and `+` operators. I also have a constructor:

```
Matrix (int row, int col, const elemType &init_val)
```

that constructs a matrix initialized to hold init_val in all positions. So based on this implementation, I have in my test program:

```
 Matrix<int> mi4 = Matrix<int> (2, 2, 3) + Matrix<int> (2, 2, 1);
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
testMatrix.cpp:41: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ in ‘Matrix<int>(2, 2, ((const int&)((const int*)(&3)))) + Matrix<int>(2, 2, ((const int&)((const int*)(&1))))’
Matrix.h:91: note: candidates are: Matrix<elemType> operator+(const Matrix<elemType>&, const Matrix<elemType>&) [with elemType = int]
```

I remember in C++ standard library, you can call constructor within an expression. How can I implement that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You left the last line out of the error message.  That will help to determine the problem.

Comment: Your error message one lists one of the candidates. Surely more than one was listed? Otherwise it wouldn't be ambiguous? (This is @DrewDormann's point I think).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not the constructor, but your declaration(s) of `operator+` for the Matrix template.  Do you have two of those (maybe you forgot to rename one of them to `operator*`)?

Comment: @KerrekSB No, leaving `const` will not cause overload ambiguity: rvalue can not be bound to a non-const reference.